# Refresh Frame AND Jump to Anchor

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, frames

I am unable to get the frame to refresh first, THEN jump to the anchor.  The order I put the commands in the onClick event seems to make no difference.  I even tried to pull them out into a function to no avail.

```
<input type="button"
onclick="edit_form.edit_mode.value=1;
edit_form.submit();
top.settings.location.reload();
top.settings.location='index.php?fuseaction=admin.displayCallReportSettings#3';"
value="Save"
name="save_button">
```

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Are you refreshing the iFrame for any reason? I assume because the "location" is the same thing, but you'd like the new content and still go to it's anchor? trying using the iFrame.location and iFrame.location.hash properties.

Comment: Left frame displays long list of settings.  Right frame allows edits and saves. I want to save the setting, then refresh the list in the left frame to update with the just saved settings, then go back down to the current spot in the list.  Does that help?

I'm using frameset and frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This because you are *initiating* frame reload, and *immediately* issuing command to go to another url. You have to assign `onload` handler and scroll that anchor into view there.

Comment: You rock.  Thanks, I needed a little nudge.

I pass the anchor through the url (PHP), then use the onload hander to jump.

Thanks again.